# Simplest way to create database filter in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Hey guys I am in a bit of a bind here. I'm a green developer in over my head and not sure where to go from here. My background is basically HTML, CSS, and JS, but I am now trying to learn PHP, SQL, and essentially build a "parts catalogue" for a company.

I have an excel file the company uses which I converted to CSV, and then imported into a MYSQL database. The basic convention is Category, Sub Category, and Manufacturer. So for example, Tires, Truck Tire, Company X. After hard coding a page to get the design right, I am now trying to move forward into Laravel and build a more diverse app. But essentially what I am trying to do is have a user click on a category, sub category, or manufacturer, and then display all those items through SQL filtering.

So while I am not looking at specific coding advice, I would love if someone would please show me where to even start. Google searching has not been very useful for me since much of what I am finding involves creating new items, editing existing items, which I do not need to do at all. I simply need to display items from the database on the page when a user clicks that particular column.

I have looked at a few articles including Pagination and REST API's, but even that is a bit over my head at this point, so I am more looking for a gentle push in the proper direction of where to go to begin doing this. I have learned the basics of Laravel, learned to setup Laravel, seed a user table, write a couple @foreach loops, and figure out how views/models operate to some degree, but I am basically a noob in this regard.

This is the PHP I wrote pre-Laravel to hard code it to just display anything under a manufacturer called Trucklite. I wrote a JS function to change the primary image by clicking on a thumbnail as well, but I won't bother posting that.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$keyword = "Trucklite";

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="SELECT part_number, item_description FROM parts WHERE 
 item_description LIKE '%{$keyword}%' LIMIT 40";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='catalogue-card'>".
        "<div class='catalogue-card-description'>".
            $row["item_description"].
        "</div>".

        "<div class='catalogue-card-inner'>".
            "<br /><br />".
            "<a id='image-link' href='/img/".
             $row['part_number'].
             " A.jpeg'".
             " data-fancybox='gallery'><img class='full' id='".
             // $row["part_number"].
             "full-image".
             "'".
             "style='height:200px;' src='/img/".
             $row["part_number"].
             " A.jpeg'></a>".

            "<br /><br />".

            "<img class='thumb' style='height: 50px;' src='/img/".
              $row['part_number'].
              " A.jpeg'>".

            "<img class='thumb' style='height: 50px;' src='/img/".
              $row["part_number"].
              " B.jpeg'>".

            "<img class='thumb' style='height: 50px;' src='/img/".
              $row["part_number"].
              " C.jpeg'>".

            "<img class='thumb' style='height: 50px;' src='/img/".
              $row["part_number"].
              " D.jpeg'>".

            "<br /><br />".

            "<span>Part #: </span>".
              $row["part_number"].
              "<br/><br />".
        "</div>".
    "</div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

So of course this is a really non-elegant way to demo thing visually, but not much beyond that. Any help would be appreciated, and forgive me if I am being ignorant, but I am really feeling frustrated and not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel use Eloquent ORM so you don't need to struggle with all this db connection.
To setup laravel with your database you have to correct your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

The next step is to create your Model
`php artisan make:model Part`
After you make it you can use all the data you need through eloquent.

In your example you can make like this.
file Part.php ( model)

add several code here

```
public static function getParts($part)
{
   $data = Part::where('item_description', like, '%'.$part.'%')->take(40)->get();
   return $data;
}
```

And in you controller just add at the top

```
use App\Part;
```

And you can call you function and render the data

```
public function ShowParts($part)
{
 $data = Part::getParts($part);
 return view('your_view', compact('data'));
}
```

Also make some changes in your route file
**web.php**

```
Route::get('/getpart/{part}', 'Controller@ShowParts');
```

After create the view file and use your data through **@foreach**

```
@foreach($data as $row)
<div>{{$row->part_number}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Hope this will help you